# Have windows desktop.ini files stored elsewhere on my system

Tags: windows-10

I am tired of `desktop.ini` files gunking up my projects and cloud drives. Is there any group policy or a way of changing the default location of each folder's desktop.ini file?

Like for example, system wide, all desktop.ini files could be stored in an sqlite database, or system registry, or added to a corresponding `AppData/local` subfolder.

edit: I am not interested in hiding the view of these files, as I need the ability to see all hidden files and folders even ones marked as `system`

Comment: What you want isn’t possible.  A Desktop.ini file store in AppData/Local would only apply to that folder.  This is a fundamental feature of Windows.

Comment: Other than the default user folders, 'normal' folders only acquire a **desktop.ini** file if you assign a custom icon. If you don't assingn  a custom icon, the file won't be created. Or you could allow Explorer to hide system files.

Comment: I have exceedingly few INI files for my applications (maybe one or two) . Are you sure your apps use INI files?   The above is correct about belonging to specific things so no central location

Comment: @Ramhound that is actually not true. Yes the desktop.ini file is a file that contains settings for that folder, but you can actually disable the ability to save settings for a folder per group policy, which will stop windows from creating desktop.ini files. It will also stop the user from having the view of a folder altered and stored for that folder though, but that is usually an acceptable compromise.

Comment: @KeithMiller that's not true. If you set the folder to details view, while normally you have list view, and you have enabled to store individual settings for each folder, the desktop.ini is also created.

Comment: @LPChip - You can stop the creation of the file but you cannot configure it to create the file in another location.  My statement was specifically about creating Desktop.ini in another location other than the folder it exists in.

Comment: You said " need the ability to see all hidden files "  I searched my system. Almost all (over 99%) are in c:\windows and most of those are in WinSXS or SysWow.  So they do not appear (to me) of being of much interest in regular work

Comment: @LPChip: you are mistaken. Icon mode, sort key/order, grouping, and column choice are all saved in the registry (HKCR\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags). But, the other common action I forget to mention is over-riding the default (sniffed) folder type via the **Customize** tab in the folder's **Properties** dialog.